# Updates to thread-local bindings in Clojure done with set! not taking place?

Tags: clojure

I'm trying to use `set!` to modify the thread-local bindings of a var -- but these changes don't appear to be taking effect. Consider the following:

```
(def ^:dynamic *foo* :root)
(binding [*foo* :thread-local]
  (let [val (doto :new
               #(set! *foo* %))]
    [val *foo*]))
```

I would expect the result to be `[:new :new]`; instead, this evaluates to `[:new :thread-local]`. What am I misunderstanding here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `doto` syntax is wrong.

```
(binding [*foo* :thread-local]
  (let [val (doto :new (#(set! *foo* %)))]
    [val *foo*]))
```

Note the additional parens.

Comment: Thanks! (Also -- looks like set! returns the value, so the doto was completely unnecessary to start with. Heh).